# adding a custom rule in default asp.net login system

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Hi guys I'm working on a project in which we can disable our users. There is a column name status in user table that can be true or false. Now I want to add a new rule in default asp.net user login that if a user is disable(his column name status equals false), should not able to login with an error message that "Admin have disabled your account".

I have looked in,

```
ManageController.cs
IdentityConfig.cs
ManageViewModles.cs
IdentityModel.cs
```

but I didn't get any clue. How can I add this rule in my asp.net MVC-5 application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In login method of account controller i achieved it using this code.

I updated code in my switch(result) of case SignInStatus.Success:

case SignInStatus.Success:

```
            var userID = SignInManager.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity.GetUserId();
            AspNetUser res = db.AspNetUsers.Where(x => x.Id == userID).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
            if (res.Status == "False")
            {
                AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                // return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Admin has disabled your account.");
                return View(model);
            }
//remaining code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a verification with an async function in your login view controller and call it on Login button press.

Good place to start: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)

**EDIT**

Here some code sample you could have in your HomeController->Index Action. Note that this isn't async but you could implement an async action with your db call:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Verification of user

        //if true
        return View();

       //else false
       return ErrorView(); //View that contains the error message
    }
```

Comment: Your message could be returned by the function to the view itself

Comment: where can i find that controller

Comment: @Azeem112 I've updated answer. If your login brings you to the home page of your website I suppose you should have wheter a HomeController or a LoginController.

Comment: @J.Lavoie why not use a datanotation instead?

Comment: @StuiterSlurf true, it might be a better way of doing this, but I think he firstly need to find out his homepage/login controller!